# insert Excel sheet in Word 2003 and keep formula?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word

Is it possible to insert an Excel sheet, formula and all, into word and keep the functionality of the formula within Word?

Answer (score 2):

Copy your Excel data and in Word use the Paste Special option. Choose Paste As Microsoft Excel Worksheet Object. When you double click the resulting object in Word you can edit in Excel.